# MS-Access SQL difficulties with conditional filtering

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in MS-Access that I am trying to pull some values based on a condition, then sum the results.

```
SELECT SchedulingLog.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, Sum(SchedulingLog.Value) AS Gain, Sum(SchedulingLog.Value) AS Used, [Gain]+[Used] AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog
GROUP BY SchedulingLog.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, [Gain]+[Used]
HAVING ((
(SchedulingLog.Category) Like "DH*" Or 
(SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Com*") AND 
("Where[CatDetai]" Like "Gain*") AND 
("Where[CatDetai]" Like "Used*")
);
```

With these data in `SchedulingLog` ...

```
Userid LogDate EventDate Category CatDetail Value
abc123  1-1-11    7-2-11 DH       DH Used      -1
abc123  1-1-11    7-4-11 DH       DH Gain       1
```

... I want my query to give me this result set:

```
Userid Category Gain Used Left
abc123 DH          1   -1    0
```

Comment: Would you explain the HAVING conditions?

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: It is asking me to input the Gain value and Used Value.

Comment: I cannot think of any case where `("Where[CatDetai]" Like "Gain*")` would work. Have you tried using the query design window to build this query?

Comment: This is basically a time off log, recording gained holiday and used holiday time. The Log records the data.. Userid LogDate EventDate Category CatDetail Value abc123 1-1-11 7-2-11 DH DH Used -1 abc123 1-1-11 7-4-11 DH DH Gain 1 so in this example the displayed query information would be Userid Category Gain Used Left abc123 DH 1 -1 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL returns what you asked for based on testing with your sample data in Access 2007.

```
SELECT
    Userid,
    Category,
    Sum(IIf(CatDetail ALike '%Gain', [Value], 0)) AS Gain,
    Sum(IIf(CatDetail ALike '%Used', [Value], 0)) AS Used,
    [Gain] + [Used] AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog
GROUP BY
    Userid,
    Category
```

However, if you don't actually need to see the separate values for `Gain` and `Used`, it would be simpler to do it this way:

```
SELECT
    Userid,
    Category,
    Sum([Value]) AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog
GROUP BY
    Userid,
    Category
```